# C Issue #4 - Double-Linked List Delete All Odd Numbers From a Doubly Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to **delete all odd numbers from a doubly linked list.**
I understand the rough concept, but I am having trouble with implementing it in C.
Hope someone could help me out with this!

*This is the code that I wrote for this. All the best!*

```
typedef struct lista
{
    int broj;
    struct lista *prev;
    struct lista *next;
}Lista;

Lista *MakeNew ();
Lista *AllocateNode ();
void AddOnEnd ( Lista **p);
int DeleteOddNumbers( Lista **p );
void PrintList ( Lista *p);

int main()
{
    int i, n; printf("N: "); scanf("%d", &n); putchar('\n');
    Lista *lista_brojeva;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
        AddOnEnd(&lista_brojeva);
    
    int a; 
    a = DeleteOddNumbers(&lista_brojeva);
    PrintList(lista_brojeva);
}

int DeleteOddNumbers( Lista **p )
{
    Lista *tmp = *p;

    if ( tmp != NULL && tmp->broj % 2 != 0 )
    {
        *p = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while ( tmp != NULL && tmp->broj % 2 != 0 )
            tmp = tmp->next;
        
        if ( tmp == NULL ) return 0;
        
        tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it were me, I would write a function that deletes the node you are currently at and returns a pointer to the next node.  Then you can make a loop that says "while not at the end if the node is odd, delete me."

Comment: Also, please see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to be able to ask questions to actually help others.

Comment: I think that the main problem with your code is not with the C implementation but with your design. See, you are literally using the exact same condition in the `if` statement and the first `while` loop of the `else` statement. If you double check the flow, you should see this kind of problems. I would really, really check the design before asking. If you REALLY work on it, you will also have a more specific question to ask, if you still have questions at all.

Comment: Hi Dario and Jerry, I wasn't aware of the 2 links that you sent me, I have just opened stack overflow and was practicing and didn't know how to solve certain problems so I asked here and got much done! I have solved the issue thanks to your help as @JerryJeremiah explained but I am more considerate about the design and the way I ask my questions, Thank you, Dario Rodriguez!

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to allocate a new list and to push each even node back to it, then free the first list.
This way, your `DeleteOddNumbers` function should be very simple:

```
void delete_odd_numbers(t_lst **lst)
{
    t_lst   *new_lst = NULL;
    t_lst   *tmp = *lst;

    while (tmp)
    {
        if (tmp->value % 2 == 0)
            push_back(&new_lst, tmp->value);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    free_lst(*lst);
    *lst = new_lst;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Will definitely try this out, all the best!